# How to provide inputs runtime in python testcases

Tags: python, variables, input, runtime

While writing test cases for python methods, how to provide inputs automatically to variables without prompting user to enter input ?

```
def function():
    speed = input('Enter speed:\n')
    if speed == 10:
        pass
    else:
        pass
```

For the above code if we call the method , it'll prompt user to enter input for speed.

```
>>> function()
Enter speed:
10
```

Is there any way to pass input using any functions or to skip a line and assign value for the variable? 
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The `function` could be written to accept the test mode, simplest way is with a default `None` argument:

```
def function(speed=None):
    if speed is None:
        speed = input('Enter speed:\n')
    if speed == 10:
        pass
    else:
        pass
```

That way, it can still be called like before (it will run the `input` part):

```
function()
```

Or with different "inputs" during testing:

```
function(5)
function(10)
for i in range(33,50):
    function(i)
```